# How to redirect multiple dynamic URLS with apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect multiple paths some with dynamic path names that can be anything.

For example:

- http://www.aaa.com/ => http://www.bbb.com/nl/
- http://www.aaa.com/en/ => http://www.bbb.com/en/
- http://www.aaa.com/portfolio/(dynamic-name) => http://www.bbb.com/nl/media
- http://www.aaa.com/en/portfolio/(dynamic-name) => http://www.bbb.com/en/media
- http://www.aaa.com/media/(dynamic-name) => http://www.bbb.com/nl/media
- http://www.aaa.com/en/media/(dynamic-name) => http://www.bbb.com/en/media
- http://www.aaa.com/team => http://www.bbb.com/nl/about-us
- http://www.aaa.com/en/team=> http://www.bbb.com/en/about-us

This is the code I have now.

```
RewriteEngine on

RedirectMatch "^/" "http://www.bbb.ai/nl/"
RedirectMatch "^/en/" "http://www.bbb.ai/en/"

RedirectMatch "^/media/" "http://www.bbb.ai/nl/media/"
RedirectMatch "^/media/(.*)" "http://www.bbb.ai/nl/media/"
RedirectMatch "^/en/media/" "http://www.bbb.ai/en/media/"
RedirectMatch "^/en/media/(.*)" "http://www.bbb.ai/en/media/"

RedirectMatch "^/portfolio/" "http://www.bbb.ai/nl/media/"
RedirectMatch "^/portfolio/(.*)" "http://www.bbb.ai/nl/media/"
RedirectMatch "^/en/portfolio/" "http://www.bbb.ai/en/media/"
RedirectMatch "^/en/portfolio/(.*)" "http://www.bbb.ai/en/media/"

RedirectMatch "^/team/(.*)" "http://www.bbb.ai/nl/about-us"
RedirectMatch "^/en/team/(.*)" "http://www.bbb.ai/en/about-us"
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code in your question suggests you may be confusing two techniques of URL rewriting. `RewriteEngine On` provides `RewriteRule` functionality by `mod_rewrite`, but `RedirectMatch` is part of `mod_alias`.

Using either correctly should yield the correct solution for your scenario, but I will make use of `RewriteRule` here, so ensure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled on your server. I have also made an assumption that these rules are in your `VirtualHost` and not an `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine on

# /
RewriteRule "^/$" "http://www.bbb.ai/nl/" [R,L]
RewriteRule "^/team/?$" "http://www.bbb.ai/nl/about-us" [R,L]
RewriteRule "^/media/.+" "http://www.bbb.ai/nl/media/" [R,L]
RewriteRule "^/portfolio/.+" "http://www.bbb.ai/nl/media/" [R,L]

# /en
RewriteRule "^/en/?$" "http://www.bbb.ai/en/" [R,L]
RewriteRule "^/en/team/?$" "http://www.bbb.ai/en/about-us" [R,L]
RewriteRule "^/en/media/.+" "http://www.bbb.ai/en/media/" [R,L]
RewriteRule "^/en/portfolio/.+" "http://www.bbb.ai/en/media/" [R,L]
```

At the root URLs, the end anchor `$` is used to make sure that they will redirect only when nothing else is present. For media and portfolio, you state in the question that they should redirect only when followed by something dynamic.

If you actually want to redirect both `/portfolio` and `/portfolio/something-dynamic`, you can do so like:

```
RewriteRule "^/en/portfolio(/.*)?" "http://www.bbb.ai/en/portfolio/" [R,L]
```

And given media and portfolio both have the same destination, you could actually combine as below:

```
RewriteRule "^/en/(media|portfolio)/.+" "http://www.bbb.ai/en/media/" [R,L]
```

Though this is less code, it is also less readable, so bear that in mind when activating the rules.

Comment: How do we do, if we want to redirect /media/<dynamic> to /assets/<dynamic>. Retain the dynamic value but replace media to assets